# Ramda changing Date to empty array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a function (removeNullOrEmpty) that removes empty or null variables, it works flawless.

But, I noticed when I pass a Date object, this function transform into a empty array and I don't know why

```
import { pipe, reject, either, isNil, isEmpty, map, when, is } from 'ramda'

export const removeNullOrEmpty = (o) =>
  pipe(reject(either(isNil, isEmpty)), map(when(is(Object), removeNullOrEmpty)))(o)
```

```
const timestamp = new Date(Date.now()) // timestamp is a valid instance of Date 

const result = removeNullOrEmpty({ timestamp  })

console.log(result) // HERE timestamp is an empty array
```

`{ timestamp: [] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `is (Object)` (correctly) identifies a Date as an Object, but the [code for `map`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/b17c8e2f200d1b006033028db73771b3e09ac1b3/source/map.js#L46-l58) uses a common trick to identify plain objects, and defaults to an [array version](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/b17c8e2f200d1b006033028db73771b3e09ac1b3/source/internal/_map.js) when the input is not a plain object.

As a member of the Ramda team, I would appreciate it if you'd be willing to [raise an issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new) reporting this.  It really should be fixed.

Meanwhile, I'm guessing that you've already realized this, but you can work around this with the fairly ugly:

```js
const removeNullOrEmpty = (o) => pipe (
  reject (either (isNil, isEmpty)), 
  map (when (both (is (Object), complement (is (Date))), removeNullOrEmpty))
) (o)
```

or perhaps

```js
const removeNullOrEmpty = unary (pipe (
  reject (either (isNil, isEmpty)), 
  map (when (both (is (Object), complement (is (Date))), removeNullOrEmpty))
))
```